# Sparkle - binding doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sparkle

I'm trying to implement Sparkle into my project and it works fine, but I have one problem:

I can't get these bindings to work (automaticallyCheckForUpdates etc.).

I added a check button, as the documentation described, but when I bind to Updater (which is an object in my nib) the Model Key Path doesn't recognize the methods:
[image: setting bind to SUUpater]

I set up Updater to be from the class SUUpdater and also my NSButton ("Check For Updates") works fine (linked to Updater-object)...

Also the settings appear in my plist correctly so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared the project several times and suddenly it worked. I've no clue what happened.